# Get all keys from Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Given the following struct in Swift:

```
Array<(key: String, value:Double)>()
```

How can i get an array of keys and an array of values?

Comment: That's a really suspicious type. Why isn't this a `Dictionary` or `KeyValuePairs`? Anyway, what you're looking for is [`Array.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map)

Comment: At least, show an example of an array that you are talking about.

Comment: If you got this from a Dictionary, the dictionary itself will give you an array of keys and an array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
let arr = Array<(key: String, value:Double)>()
let keys = arr.map {$0.key}
let values = arr.map {$0.value}
```